# Using Opencv API ( Exposure Compensator class ) in stitching module

Tags: opencv, opencv-stitching

I'm trying to fill the holes (after I eliminate the foreground) in an image (img1) using another image (img2) that contains that information.

After warping img2 using my method by an Homograpy (H), I would take information from img2_warped to fill in the img1. Then I want to do exposure compensation.

Now I see OpenCV provide a module (stitching) [Exposure Compensator class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/exposure_compensation.html) that I can possibly use. My problem is that in

```
compensator->feed(corners, images, masks);
```

what is the exact meaning of the input top-left corners and masks? And how can I generate them in my case?

I've seen the stitching sample but I am really doing something different from stitching so I can't use its "warp" function to produce the "coners".

For example I have these two images.

The corners produced are

Corner #0 : [-270, 325]

Corner #1 : [-86, 327]

Sorry that I am not able to attach the images because of the reputation.
Does anyone can explain the meaning of the corners?

Comment: See the same question I asked.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010908/the-meaning-of-opencv-exposure-compensator-class/16547767#16547767