# The meaning of OpenCV Exposure Compensator class

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Hi I want to use  Exposure Compensator class standalone.
Does anyone knows the meaning following input arguments?

```
compensator->feed(corners, images, masks);
```

For example when I was stitching two images I got two corners:

Corner #0 : [-270, 325]

Corner #1 : [-86, 327]

How can the top-left conrner be a negative value? What's the meaning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I make it clear. It's just the top-left corner of the image in the BIG map. Since this class is especially for images [stitching](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html), after registration, the warped images can have different positions.

Simply use for two ready (warped) images, giving the two corners [0, 0] is just fine.

Comment: Could you explain further? Do you have any sample code for it? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978689/balancing-contrast-and-brightness-between-stitched-images) is another similar question also requiring more details. Cheers.